# Deploying rails app to EC2 using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

So I'm going through this tutorial http://blog.grio.com/2012/07/how-to-deploy-your-web-app-to-amazon-ec2-using-capistrano.html to deploy a rails app to EC2, and I'm confused about a few things in deploy.rb.  In the default version of the file, I have:

```
role :web, "your web-server here"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "your app-server here"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "your primary db-server here", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
role :db,  "your slave db-server here"
```

However, previously I was hosting on heroku where I was assigned a url.  Since this will be a facebook app, I don't want to deal with getting a url, so is there anything I can do to get one automatically like I did on heroku?  Also, what is the idea behind this, ie what is it doing?

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/myapp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run Capistrano, you are running it from your local machine.

The:

```
"your web-server here"
```

is for the IP address of the remote server you are deploying your app to.

The:

```
set :deploy_to
```

is specifying the folder on the server you want.